# Draw flipped image on canvas

Tags: android

My application overlays camera preview with a picture and the saves with the overlay on it when captured.
But when i capture using front camera it shows the mirror of camera preview.
Now i want to flip the image when using front camera but when i capture the overlay image"mark" is not saved with the captured image.
What am i doing wrong?

```
                     {

                      Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                     int   wid = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
                     int  hgt = cameraBitmap.getHeight(); 
                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wid+""+hgt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);
                      if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                           {
                      canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
                          }
                      else 
                      {
                          canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
                         // newImage = flip(newImage);
                          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                          matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
                            // unknown type
                            // return transformed image
                            newImage= Bitmap.createBitmap(newImage, 0, 0, newImage.getWidth(), newImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                          canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
                      }
                     Drawable drawable getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark);
                      drawable.setBounds(20, 30, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()+20, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()+30);
                     drawable.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[How to overlay an image or view on top of a camera captured image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260706/how-to-overlay-an-image-or-view-on-top-of-a-camera-captured-image)

Comment: Hey, you are making reflection of an image
I need to overlay a drawable "mark" to flipped image.
But when i flip, the overlay disappears
I need help on this part :